# Reference error: TinyMce is not defined on my Umbraco 8.18.9 site

Tags: tinymce, umbraco

I have a site running Umbraco 8.6.1. No changes has been made to the site recently but I started getting these errors in my umbraco logs -

[Umbraco Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFtaI.png)

When checking the console the error reads -

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XIwI.png)

I set up a copy on a test enviroment and upgraded Umbraco from 8.6.1 to 8.18.9. The changes were successfull but the error persists.

I have no idea how to proceed and old Umbraco forum posts seem to have outdated solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would debug this issue like this:

Try with compilation debug on in the web.config. It seems like you are missing some files, and sometimes if your run in debug mode, the system isn't so picky.

To resolve the issue, you could:

1. take a backup or make sure everything is checked in git
2. Start a clean website with exactly the version (download at
   https://our.umbraco.com/download/releases/)
3. Install a website
   (without a starterkit).
4. Take all files from the clean installation and overwrite them in your current website
5. Start your broken website